# My dropdown button appear behind the search bar

Tags: html, css

I need a help to custom my dropdown nav bar, look at the picture
The dropdown list appears behind the search bar. How i can make it appear in normal way?

[image]

thank you

Comment: Increase Navbar  z-index value

Comment: @HamidShoja thank you sir , i solved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can increase Navbar z-index value in css

like

```
Navbar {
   z-index:99 // or greater than search input z-index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the nav's `z-index` should be greater than the search-bar

```
.nav {
    z-index: 1000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `z-index` of nav-bar grather than other elements.
For example:

```
.nav-bar { z-index: 9999 }
```